# is this a good design of the database?

Tags: database, database-design

I have four tables. Manufactures, ProductionPlants, ProducitonLine and Machines. Machines are the machines that are used to manufacture some prduct.

A manufacture can have many plants and a plant can have many production lines can have many machines. So all the relationships are 1:N.

So the tables have the following fields:

```
Manufactures      (IDManufacture,...)
ProductionPlant   (IDProductionPlant, IDManufacture,...)
ProductionLine    (IDProductionLine, IDPlant,...)
Machines          (IDMachine, IDProductionLine,...)
```

However, this makes that a machine must be installed always in a line fo production, but sometimes a machine can be uninstalled, not used, but still is property of a manufacture.

In the disign, if I set null the IDProductionLine field in the machine table, then I don't be able to know the manufacture that has this machine.

SO the first solution is to add other field to the Machines table, the IDManufacture, so I can set null IDProductionLine but still can know the owner.

But my doubt if this is a good solution, because this create a cycle in the relationships, because from Machines, I can know the manufacture by the IDMachine or by the LineProducion-->PlantProduction. is this a problem or is a good solution?

When to elimiate cycles and when is admissible to have a cycle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would decouple Machines (Machine inventory in a specific product line) from your types of machines to make this more normalized -

```
Manufacturer
 1:N
Prod Plant
 1:N
Prod Line
 1:N
Machine Inventory
 N:1
Machine Type
```

The machine type table would store 1 row for every type of machine used at the company, and machine inventory would contain unique information for every instance of a machine used in a specific product line.  With this structure you would be able to remove a machine from a product line, and still maintain details about the machine in your database.  There would also be less redundancy with this structure should you be using multiple instances of the same machine or using the same type of machine in different product lines or plants as all those machine inventory rows would point back to the machine type.

Comment: the database is a very small DB, and I don't need information about the type. However, in your example, how I create the union between manufacturer and machine inventory? In your example I only see the relaion between Machine inventory and Prod line. If I delete a prod line, could I know which manufacturer is the owner of the machine inventory?

Comment: Yeah, by Machine Type, I simply mean information describing the machine, this machine type table (or whatever you want to call it) could have a direct relationship to the manufacturer.  The machine inventory table would simply relate instances of your machine to a product line.  Basically, I'd recommend having a separate table that relates the machine to the manufacturer since you are using your current machine table as more of an inventory for what machines are in a specific product line, and the current structure you have won't support removing a machine from a product line.

Comment: then if I delete a product line, I don't be able to know which is the owner of the machines of this product line, because if product line is the only way to realtion machines with manufacturers, I can't delete a product line without lost this information (which is the owner of each machine, is in a product line or not).

Comment: Well it all comes down to your requirements, if you need to retain the manufacturer - machine relationship, you should put in a direct relationship.  On the other hand, if a machine needs to be bound to a product line then why not keep your existing structure and instead of deleting the product line, have a status column on it and make the status of the product line deactivated?  This would allow you to filter the product line out of reports, but you would still be able to track the machine against it and its manufacturer.

Comment: The status column is a good option, but I know that in the future is very possible that will want to delete lines and plants. I prefer not delete information, only deacitvate as you say, but I don't know why is very common that the users want to delete information.

Comment: Yeah that's something I've hit in the past with customers, usually explaining the benefits of not deleting the data will drive the customer to accept deactivation of records over permanent deletion.  In any case, if you do offer deletion, it sounds like a delete anywhere in your structure should probably cascade all the way down to the machine level since otherwise you would end up with orphaned machine records.